# Sql error number: 1236. Error Message: A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server

Tags: sql-server, network

I'm getting a SQL Server error:

> Execution fail against sql server. Sql error number: 1236. Error
> Message: A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results
> from the server.  (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The network
> connection was aborted by the local system.)

This occurs when I execute a stored procedure.

The stored procedure has worked well for some months. Some days ago, we moved the database to another server and get this error.

I use this proc in an ADF pine-line, and sometimes I get this error, not always but very often.
I try to remote to the server and execute directly from SSMS but the error still happens.

I have tried to research in many forums, but there is no solution that fixed my case.
How can I resolve this? Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the DBA StackExchange forum. I understand you already researched many forums. Have you seen [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/64409/a-transport-level-error-has-occurred-when-sending-the-request-to-the-server) post?

Comment: Yes, I have. And no solution work for me.

Comment: When you execute the procedure in SSMS, are you executing it on the local server it lives on or are you executing from another server that has to make a remote call to the procedure?

Comment: I executed it on the local server that it lives on.

Comment: If this fails when run locally it's probably not a network issue.  So the other possibility is that the session was aborted by the server, perhaps because of a severe error or crash.  The SQL Server ERRORLOG should have more information.

Comment: It's not easy for me to remote to the server machine so now I cannot check the ERRORLOG.
But when I changed the connection from ".\sqlexpress01,1433" to "[IP address]\\sqlexpress01,1433", there weren't any errors happen in many days.
I don't know the reason.